# stuck in finding index value in clojure

Tags: clojure, indexing

I want to write a program in `clojure` that would return only the first index value of `true` values from my function. My code goes here:

```
 (defn func [f x] (map f x))
```

So, if I give a value like:

```
(func zero? [1 1 1 0 3 7 0 2])
```

It gives me:

```
(false false false true false false true false)
```

and if I give:

```
(func (fn [n] (= n 6)) [:cat :dog :six :blorg 6])
```

It returns:

```
(false false false false true)
```

But, what I want is `index value` of `first true`. Like for

```
(func zero? [1 1 1 0 3 7 0 2]) => 3 (desired result)
(func (fn [n] (= n 6)) [:cat :dog :six :blorg 6]) => 4 (desired result)
(func zero? [1 1 3 7 2]) => nil (desired result)
```

Can anybody suggest how to get the `first index` value of `true`?

Comment: "stuck in" should be your trade mark for questioning! :)

Comment: better you suggest some other title :P

Comment: Comments in stackover flow isn't for chatting and long discussions.

Comment: no this question doesn't have a duplicate, as you can see my comments of `Winkler`, this is something different that I want

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, so I found out an answer for my question itself:

```
(defn indices [pred coll]
  (keep-indexed #(when (pred %2) %1) coll))

  (defn tun [f x]
    (first (indices true? 
              (vec (map f x)))))
```

and if you do:

```
(tun zero? [1 1 3 7 2]) => nil (the exact desired result)
```

Comment: So, the link I posted in the comment was correct!

Comment: ok so I didn't see the later answers, but I didn't get the solution from there

Answer (score 1):

```
 (count (take-while not '(false false false true false false true false)))
 => 3

 (.indexOf '(false true) true)
 => 1
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but it works for only cases where `true` value is present. For cases where `true` is not present like: `(fun nil? [])` is shows `0` whereas it should have shown `nil` as mentioned in my question. Like for `(func zero? [1 1 3 7])` it's returning `4` but it should have returned `nil`, which means when `true` is not present it's just count the number of elements, so it's showing values `0` and `4`. So this is not a correct answer.

Comment: no your edited answer returns `-1` given the above cases. I think I have figured out the answer and will post in few minutes after all test cases.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you posted yourself seems slightly overcomplicated. It can be simplified to this:

```
(defn first-indexed [pred coll]
  (first (keep-indexed (fn [idx itm]
                         (when (pred itm)
                           idx))
                       coll)))
```

i.e. the `true? (vec (map` part of `tun` is unnecessary.